Source for the Stotra
Saint Shri Premanand Ji is suggesting this shloka to avoid lust, anger and other pancha bhautik vikaras. Can anyone give proper reference of this shloka?
सदानन्दं वृन्दावन नवलता मन्दिरवरे
ष्वमन्दैः कन्दर्पोन्मद रतिकला कौतुक रसम्।
किशोरं तत्ज्योतिर्युगुलं मतिघोरं मम भवं
ज्वलज्ज्वालं  शीतैः स्वपद-मकरन्दैः शमयतु ॥

This shloka is from Sri Radha rasa Sudha Nidhi Text 151. Translation by Kushakratha das.

May the effulgent youthful divine couple, who eternally enjoy blissful passionate amorous pastimes in a newly blossoming vine cottage in the Vrindavana forest, with the cooling nectar of Their feet extinguish for me the terrible flames that are the world of birth and death.
